# Why these two strings are not the same in PHP?

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
$city = $_GET['city'];
$cityfinal = htmlentities($city, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8");

similar_text($cityfinal, "CITY OF BIÑAN", $percent); 

echo "Differnce between " . $cityfinal . " and CITY OF BIÑAN is " . $percent;
```

Result:

> Difference between CITY OF BIÑAN and CITY OF BIÑAN is 72.7272727273

Comment: What you want ?? percent is 0??

Comment: Character `Ñ` encodes as `&#xD1;` and that's means texts `CITY OF BI&#xD1;AN` and `CITY OF BIÑAN` is not the same

Comment: How can achieve result on this one, sorry I am new in php. $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT barangay FROM operations WHERE provinces = '$province' And cities = '$cityfinal' order by barangay");

Answer (score 1):

Your compared string is not converted in htmlentities so its giving you difference. Try to convert it and check.

Here special character `BIÑAN` encoded in `$_GET['city']` string but remaining with given comparision string.

```
$city = $_GET['city'];
$checkcity ="CITY OF BIÑAN";
$cityfinal = htmlentities($city, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8");
$cityCheckwith = htmlentities($checkcity, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8");

similar_text($cityfinal, $cityCheckwith, $percent); 

echo "Differnce between " . $cityfinal . " and CITY OF BIÑAN is " . $percent;
```

**Output**

> Differnce between CITY OF BIAN and CITY OF BIÑAN is 100

**Check Online Demo : [Click Here](https://eval.in/573028)**

Comment: Use above code it works definatly and meets your expectation. @Kacey Manalac

Comment: The reason I asked is because I am getting a null result in my query: $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT barangay FROM operations WHERE `provinces` = '$province' And `cities` = '$cityfinal' order by barangay");

Comment: Try to use LIKE : `$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT barangay FROM operations WHERE provinces LIKE %'$province'% And cities LIKE %'$cityfinal'% order by barangay`

Comment: Try to use trim() and also paste your query with $province and $cityfinal data. and cross check it with database values.

Comment: Yes when I do this in the database i'm getting the result I want, SELECT DISTINCT barangay FROM operations WHERE provinces = 'LAGUNA' And cities = 'CITY OF BIÑAN' order by barangay but for some reason the $_Get with Ñ character doing something unusual.

Comment: yes so i am telling you to use htmlentities($cityfinal).